# how to get one record from a mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

i'am trying to get one cell from my mysql database.
this cell is unique because of the date and hour. 
so if date and time is selected with a WHERE it should come back with one number.
I checked everything but it still doesnt work. i get zero returns.

does anyone see something wrong with my code?

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chairs` WHERE `date` = '$date' AND `hour` = '$hour' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
$dbchairs = $row[$chairs];

echo $dbchairs;
```

Comment: use mysql_fetch_row();

Comment: You shouldn't have ask such a simple question here. One Google search will give you thousands of answers for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined variable chairs in

```
$dbchairs = $row[$chairs];
```

If in DB is column called `chairs`, use:

```
$dbchairs = $row['chairs']; // key of $row array is column name
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

`$dbchairs = $row[$chairs];`
to 
`$dbchairs = $row['chairs'];`

You are using undefined variable `$chairs` as your index in `$row` array.

syntax: `$row['name_of_the_column_in_database']`